# Facebook Graph Api scope issue in iOS

Tags: codenameone

I am using the `ios.facebook_permissions=user_posts` build hint to get the permission to read user posts but the login dialog presents only the default profile, email and likes permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook now requires you to go thru an approval process for any risky permission

Comment: Yes, but before the approval process, in order to be able to test it, Facebook says that "Any account listed in the Roles tab in your App Dashboard, such as admins, developers and testers, can use all permissions.". I am testing it as admin.

Comment: Are you testing on an iOS device? The syntax for this is a bit different more like a String array: `ios.facebook_permissions="public_profile", "user_posts"`

Comment: I am testing on iOS device. I changed the syntax and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you defined the hint correctly? The previous syntax should have triggered a compilation error.

Comment: I am sure. The previous syntax did not trigger a compilation error.

Comment: This issue is holding me off so I am wondering if you have any further suggestions that I could try.

Comment: Did you wrap your calls with `askPublishPermissions` ?

Comment: This is what happens when I use `askPublishPermissions`. The first time I click the Login button the login dialog presents only the default profile, email and likes permissions. The second time I click the Login button it presents the publish permissions approval dialog. But the bigger issue is that LoginCallback is never invoked.

Comment: When asking for the publish permission you need to make the changes within the callback for that permission

Comment: I would like to point out that on Android everything works as expected, without calling `askPublishPermissions`

Comment: It should fail on both so I'm not really sure what's happening, I suggest reading the error response from Facebook to find out what's going on

Comment: To recap: 1. I don't need publish permission, I just need permission to read user posts. 2. In Android it works OK, without calling `askPublishPermissions`. Are you saying that on iOS I need to call `askPublishPermissions` in order to get permission to read user posts?

Comment: No it should work in that case. What's the error you are getting from the Facebook webservice call?

Comment: The issue is that the login screen does not present the read user posts permission. It presents the public profile, friend list and email address permissions. I am using the following build hint: `ios.facebook_permissions="email","public_profile","user_posts"`

Comment: Since the previous syntax you used should have triggered a compilation error is it possible you defined this incorrectly by editing the codenameone settings file directly?
Did you define this via the Codename One Settings app?

Comment: Yes, I defined it via Codename One Settings app.

Comment: Odd, can you look in the `codenameone_settings.properties` file and find this definition then paste it as it appears there

Comment: Here you go: `codename1.arg.ios.facebook_permissions="email","public_profile","user_posts"`

Comment: OK, I think I see something broken there. Did you define `and.facebook_permissions` by any chance? It seems it breaks the ios permissions

Comment: Yes, I did. I removed it but it still does not work.

Comment: You don't need to remove that. Anyway, we found an issue that should be addressed for next weeks update